# Is it possible to set a sequelize model column's value based off the input of another column?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

In the code below, can I set "isPrimary" based on the value of "name"?

```
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Color extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Color.init({
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    isPrimary: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Color',
  });
  return Color;
};
```

I know you can set defaultvalue to a function, but how can I get the value that was passed into "name"

Comment: Check out setters. https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/getters-setters-virtuals/#setters

Comment: @Emma thank you. If you answer, I can mark this solved :)